# DB2 Error: String data right truncation when inserting data into DB

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a web scraper that scrapes the title and description and for some URLs, I get an error:

```
[Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0109E  String data right truncation. SQLSTATE=22001] {
  error: '[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
  sqlcode: -99999,
  state: '22001'
}
```

The column for the title is VARCHAR(1024) and description VARCHAR(3072), and I even limit the string length before inserting it to 200 characters just to check, but I still get this error for some URLs.

Does this mean I'm trying to insert data that won't fit into the column?

Comment: There's probably a bug in the code that's limiting the length of the values that are inserted. I would recommend you print the length of the strings before inseting, to find out exactly what's going on. You can see the error in a simple example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=2800d8e8bec69ebab88c26c0f5e964dc

Comment: Show the code with some examples. The column length is in bytes. Strings are often in UTF-8 or other Unicode encodings and take up more bytes per character

Comment: Based on the previous comment by data_henrik, I modified impaler's fiddle example, changing the `3` in the first insert to a `ó` and it causes the same error, though there's visually only 5 characters in the string. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=33f3e44e1074cef161e640aa89aaeabd)